# Sort dataframe based on key and two columns

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following dataframe that i'm trying to sort for plotting.  What I'm trying to achieve is
1 row per key (column 1) and then  the corresponding number and date as columns.

So for example:

1 6.3 2021-01-02 14:44:11     6.3     2021-02-02 14:49:12
2 6.55 2021-01-02 14:44:12    6.55    2021-02-02 14:49:12

Etc...

The number of columns will be dynamic though.

How can I achieve such a thing?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should be achievable by using the [`.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) function.

In your case you could simply define
`df.sort_values(by=['key_column', 'number column', 'date column'], inplace=True)`
You can add more columns if you need to the argument list of `by`.
Check the docs for additional arguments such as `ascending` to customise the sort.